# neo4j ::how to set shortpath query timeout property in embedded model?

Tags: neo4j, timeout

I'm using neo4j 1.9.4  embedded model .It tooks too long when executed the shortpath query(50 milion nodes  and 600 milion relations). I read the manual and found the two properties :

```
1. conf/neo4j-server.properties
org.neo4j.server.webserver.limit.executiontime=1000
2. conf/neo4j.properties
execution_guard_enabled=true
```

But here is the question,  it seems to there isn't the 'neo4j-server.properties' file in embedded model .How can I set it ? Or the 'time out ' property is just not supported in  embedded model ?

Please help. Thanks a lot !

**code :**

```
PathFinder<Path> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(Traversal
                        .expanderForTypes(RelationshipTypes.r01, Direction.BOTH)
                        .add(RelationshipTypes.r02, Direction.BOTH), 10);
paths = finder.findAllPaths(node1, node2);
for (Path shortestPath : paths) {
    List<NodeBean> nodeList = new ArrayList<NodeBean>();
    List<String> rList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ... ...
}
```

**part of message.log :**

```
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.107+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- INITIALIZED diagnostics END ---
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.217+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names non clean shutdown detected
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.217+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=114b)
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.232+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.relationshiptypestore.db non clean shutdown detected
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.232+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.relationshiptypestore.db] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=10b)
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.232+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db.strings non clean shutdown detected
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.232+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db.strings] brickCount=10 brickSize=20864b mappedMem=20971520b (storeSize=209664b)
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.232+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys non clean shutdown detected
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.232+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys] brickCount=50 brickSize=20938b mappedMem=20971520b (storeSize=1048572b)
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.232+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db.index non clean shutdown detected
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.232+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db.index] brickCount=261 brickSize=20970b mappedMem=20971520b (storeSize=5473170b)
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.232+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db.arrays non clean shutdown detected
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.232+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db.arrays] brickCount=0 brickSize=20864b mappedMem=20971520b (storeSize=128b)
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.232+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db non clean shutdown detected
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.248+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db] brickCount=23513 brickSize=104837b mappedMem=104857600b (storeSize=2465619255b)
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.248+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.relationshipstore.db non clean shutdown detected
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.248+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.relationshipstore.db] brickCount=100000 brickSize=221826b mappedMem=104857600b (storeSize=22183075860b)
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.248+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.nodestore.db non clean shutdown detected
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.248+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.nodestore.db] brickCount=4733 brickSize=104877b mappedMem=104857600b (storeSize=496395405b)
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.248+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore non clean shutdown detected
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.248+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=54b)
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.263+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Non clean shutdown detected on log [D:\FTP\graph1.db\nioneo_logical.log.1]. Recovery started ...
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.279+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\nioneo_logical.log.1] logVersion=4730 with committed tx=1072646
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.279+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\nioneo_logical.log.1] entries found=0 lastEntryPos=16
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.279+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Opened logical log [D:\FTP\graph1.db\nioneo_logical.log.1] version=4730, lastTxId=-1 (recovered)
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.279+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: XaResourceManager[nioneo_logical.log] sorting 0 xids
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.279+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: XaResourceManager[nioneo_logical.log] checkRecoveryComplete 0 xids
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.419+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names rebuild id generator, highId=3 defragged count=0
    2014-11-24 02:06:42.934+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys rebuild id generator, highId=3 defragged count=0
    2014-11-24 02:06:46.351+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db.index rebuild id generator, highId=2 defragged count=0
    2014-11-24 02:06:46.444+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db.strings rebuild id generator, highId=1490 defragged count=0
    2014-11-24 02:06:46.538+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db.arrays rebuild id generator, highId=1 defragged count=0
    2014-11-24 02:06:46.694+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.propertystore.db rebuild id generator, highId=60134068 defragged count=0
    2014-11-24 02:06:46.943+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.relationshipstore.db rebuild id generator, highId=672185416 defragged count=0
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.255+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore.nodestore.db rebuild id generator, highId=55117690 defragged count=0
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.349+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: D:\FTP\graph1.db\neostore rebuild id generator, highId=6 defragged count=0
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.411+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: XaResourceManager[nioneo_logical.log] recovery completed.
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.411+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Recovery on log [D:\FTP\graph1.db\nioneo_logical.log.1] completed.
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.411+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: TM opening log: D:\FTP\graph1.db\tm_tx_log.1
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.567+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: BackupServer communication server started and bound to /0.0.0.0:6362
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.599+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Non clean shutdown detected on log [D:\FTP\graph1.db\index\lucene.log.1]. Recovery started ...
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.599+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\index\lucene.log.1] logVersion=252 with committed tx=5514
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.599+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: [D:\FTP\graph1.db\index\lucene.log.1] entries found=0 lastEntryPos=16
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.599+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Opened logical log [D:\FTP\graph1.db\index\lucene.log.1] version=252, lastTxId=-1 (recovered)
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.599+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: XaResourceManager[lucene.log] sorting 0 xids
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.599+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: XaResourceManager[lucene.log] checkRecoveryComplete 0 xids
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.599+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: XaResourceManager[lucene.log] recovery completed.
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.599+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Recovery on log [D:\FTP\graph1.db\index\lucene.log.1] completed.
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- STARTED diagnostics for KernelDiagnostics:Versions START ---
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Graph Database: org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase StoreId[time:1414568675229, id:-3029933565465970314, store version: 13561656364791302]
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Kernel version: Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel 1.9.4
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Neo4j component versions:
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]:   Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel 1.9.4
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- STARTED diagnostics for KernelDiagnostics:Versions END ---
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- STARTED diagnostics for NEO_STORE_VERSIONS START ---
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Store versions:
        Store versions:
          NeoStore v0.A.0
          NodeStore v0.A.0
          RelationshipStore v0.A.0
          RelationshipTypeStore v0.A.0
          PropertyStore v0.A.0
          PropertyIndexStore v0.A.0
          StringPropertyStore v0.A.0
          ArrayPropertyStore v0.A.0
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- STARTED diagnostics for NEO_STORE_VERSIONS END ---
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- STARTED diagnostics for NEO_STORE_ID_USAGE START ---
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Id usage:

         Id usage:
         NodeStore: used=55155045 high=55155044
         RelationshipStore: used=672214420 high=672214419
         RelationshipTypeStore: used=2 high=1
         PropertyStore: used=60137055 high=60137054
         PropertyIndexStore: used=608130 high=608129
         StringPropertyStore: used=1638 high=1637
         ArrayPropertyStore: used=1 high=0
        2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org

    .neo4j]: --- STARTED diagnostics for NEO_STORE_ID_USAGE END ---
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- STARTED diagnostics for PERSISTENCE_WINDOW_POOL_STATS START ---
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- STARTED diagnostics for PERSISTENCE_WINDOW_POOL_STATS END ---
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- STARTED diagnostics for KernelDiagnostics:StoreFiles START ---
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.614+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Disk space on partition (Total / Free / Free %): 316763721728 / 32676884480 / 10
    Storage files: (filename : modification date - size)
          active_tx_log: 2014-11-21T08:52:51+0800 - 11.00 B
          index:
            lucene:
              node:
                nodes:
                  segments.gen: 2014-11-21T12:28:14+0800 - 20.00 B
                  segments_4z: 2014-11-21T12:28:14+0800 - 5.25 kB
                  _111.fdt: 2014-11-21T12:28:53+0800 - 223.40 MB
                  _111.fdx: 2014-11-21T12:28:24+0800 - 55.69 MB
                  _111.fnm: 2014-11-21T12:28:24+0800 - 18.00 B
                  _111.frq: 2014-11-21T12:28:34+0800 - 53.68 MB
                  _111.nrm: 2014-11-21T12:28:35+0800 - 6.96 MB
                  _111.prx: 2014-11-21T12:28:37+0800 - 13.92 MB
                  _111.tii: 2014-11-21T12:28:38+0800 - 1.62 MB
                  _111.tis: 2014-11-21T12:28:58+0800 - 115.02 MB
                  _1ri.fdt: 2014-11-21T12:29:40+0800 - 263.73 MB
                  _1ri.fdx: 2014-11-21T12:29:09+0800 - 63.93 MB
                  _1ri.fnm: 2014-11-21T12:29:10+0800 - 18.00 B
                  _1ri.frq: 2014-11-21T12:29:21+0800 - 61.92 MB
                  _1ri.nrm: 2014-11-21T12:29:22+0800 - 7.99 MB
                  _1ri.prx: 2014-11-21T12:29:25+0800 - 15.98 MB
                  _1ri.tii: 2014-11-21T12:29:25+0800 - 1.84 MB
                  _1ri.tis: 2014-11-21T12:29:48+0800 - 129.59 MB
                  _2lv.fdt: 2014-11-21T12:30:33+0800 - 303.36 MB
                  _2lv.fdx: 2014-11-21T12:30:01+0800 - 73.55 MB
                  _2lv.fnm: 2014-11-21T12:30:01+0800 - 18.00 B
                  _2lv.frq: 2014-11-21T12:30:14+0800 - 71.53 MB
                  _2lv.nrm: 2014-11-21T12:30:16+0800 - 9.19 MB
                  _2lv.prx: 2014-11-21T12:30:19+0800 - 18.39 MB
                  _2lv.tii: 2014-11-21T12:30:20+0800 - 2.14 MB
                  _2lv.tis: 2014-11-21T12:30:46+0800 - 150.79 MB
                  _3gr.fdt: 2014-11-21T12:31:28+0800 - 311.85 MB
                  _3gr.fdx: 2014-11-21T12:31:00+0800 - 75.61 MB
                  _3gr.fnm: 2014-11-21T12:31:00+0800 - 18.00 B
                  _3gr.frq: 2014-11-21T12:31:13+0800 - 73.59 MB
                  _3gr.nrm: 2014-11-21T12:31:15+0800 - 9.45 MB
                  _3gr.prx: 2014-11-21T12:31:18+0800 - 18.90 MB
                  _3gr.tii: 2014-11-21T12:31:19+0800 - 2.18 MB
                  _3gr.tis: 2014-11-21T12:31:46+0800 - 154.25 MB
                  _4ah.fdt: 2014-11-21T12:32:23+0800 - 306.20 MB
                  _4ah.fdx: 2014-11-21T12:31:59+0800 - 74.23 MB
                  _4ah.fnm: 2014-11-21T12:31:59+0800 - 18.00 B
                  _4ah.frq: 2014-11-21T12:32:12+0800 - 72.22 MB
                  _4ah.nrm: 2014-11-21T12:32:14+0800 - 9.28 MB
                  _4ah.prx: 2014-11-21T12:32:17+0800 - 18.56 MB
                  _4ah.tii: 2014-11-21T12:32:17+0800 - 2.14 MB
                  _4ah.tis: 2014-11-21T12:32:44+0800 - 152.60 MB
                  _4d9.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:32:34+0800 - 65.42 MB
                  _4g1.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:32:46+0800 - 65.54 MB
                  _4hz.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:32:46+0800 - 6.42 MB
                  _4ij.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:32:47+0800 - 6.44 MB
                  _4it.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:32:57+0800 - 65.35 MB
                  _4ll.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:32:58+0800 - 65.73 MB
                  _4od.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:33:09+0800 - 65.89 MB
                  _4on.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:33:00+0800 - 6.50 MB
                  _4ox.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:33:01+0800 - 6.57 MB
                  _4p7.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:33:02+0800 - 6.57 MB
                  _4ph.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:33:03+0800 - 6.60 MB
                  _4pr.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:33:05+0800 - 6.60 MB
                  _4px.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:33:05+0800 - 718.54 kB
                  _4py.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:33:05+0800 - 723.03 kB
                  _4pz.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:33:05+0800 - 719.12 kB
                  _4q1.cfs: 2014-11-21T12:33:07+0800 - 6.59 MB
                  _gf.fdt: 2014-11-21T12:33:29+0800 - 131.96 MB
                  _gf.fdx: 2014-11-21T12:33:15+0800 - 33.04 MB
                  _gf.fnm: 2014-11-21T12:33:15+0800 - 18.00 B
                  _gf.frq: 2014-11-21T12:33:20+0800 - 31.02 MB
                  _gf.nrm: 2014-11-21T12:33:21+0800 - 4.13 MB
                  _gf.prx: 2014-11-21T12:33:23+0800 - 8.26 MB
                  _gf.tii: 2014-11-21T12:33:23+0800 - 1.01 MB
                  _gf.tis: 2014-11-21T12:33:33+0800 - 73.32 MB
                - Total: 2014-11-24T10:06:47+0800 - 3.51 GB
              - Total: 2014-11-21T12:28:14+0800 - 3.51 GB
            - Total: 2014-11-21T12:28:14+0800 - 3.51 GB
            lucene-store.db: 2014-11-22T17:39:30+0800 - 40.00 B
            lucene.log.1: 2014-11-21T18:34:32+0800 - 16.00 B
            lucene.log.active: 2014-11-21T18:33:31+0800 - 4.00 B
          - Total: 2014-11-22T11:40:56+0800 - 3.51 GB
          index.db: 2014-11-21T08:52:48+0800 - 103.00 B
          lock: 2014-11-22T15:32:04+0800 - 0.00 B
          messages.log: 2014-11-24T10:06:44+0800 - 37.60 MB
          neostore: 2014-11-24T10:06:42+0800 - 54.00 B
          neostore.id: 2014-11-24T10:06:47+0800 - 9.00 B
          neostore.nodestore.db: 2014-11-22T15:32:04+0800 - 473.40 MB
          neostore.nodestore.db.id: 2014-11-24T10:06:47+0800 - 9.00 B
          neostore.propertystore.db: 2014-11-22T15:32:04+0800 - 2.30 GB
          neostore.propertystore.db.arrays: 2014-11-22T15:32:04+0800 - 128.00 B
          neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.id: 2014-11-24T10:06:46+0800 - 9.00 B
          neostore.propertystore.db.id: 2014-11-24T10:06:46+0800 - 9.00 B
          neostore.propertystore.db.index: 2014-11-22T17:03:23+0800 - 5.22 MB
          neostore.propertystore.db.index.id: 2014-11-24T10:06:46+0800 - 9.00 B
          neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys: 2014-11-22T15:32:04+0800 - 1024.00 kB
          neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.id: 2014-11-24T10:06:42+0800 - 9.00 B
          neostore.propertystore.db.strings: 2014-11-22T15:32:04+0800 - 204.75 kB
          neostore.propertystore.db.strings.id: 2014-11-24T10:06:46+0800 - 9.00 B
          neostore.relationshipstore.db: 2014-11-22T15:32:04+0800 - 20.66 GB
          neostore.relationshipstore.db.id: 2014-11-24T10:06:46+0800 - 9.00 B
          neostore.relationshiptypestore.db: 2014-11-24T10:06:42+0800 - 10.00 B
          neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.id: 2014-11-24T10:06:42+0800 - 9.00 B
          neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names: 2014-11-22T15:32:04+0800 - 114.00 B
          neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names.id: 2014-11-24T10:06:42+0800 - 9.00 B
          nioneo_logical.log.1: 2014-11-22T15:32:23+0800 - 16.00 B
          nioneo_logical.log.active: 2014-11-22T15:32:04+0800 - 4.00 B
          nioneo_logical.log.v4729: 2014-11-22T15:31:23+0800 - 16.00 B
          store_lock: 2014-11-21T12:21:37+0800 - 0.00 B
          tm_tx_log.1: 2014-11-24T10:06:47+0800 - 0.00 B
          tm_tx_log.2: 2014-11-21T12:21:38+0800 - 28.68 kB
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.630+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: --- STARTED diagnostics for KernelDiagnostics:StoreFiles END ---
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.630+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Started - database is now available
    2014-11-24 02:06:47.630+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: GC Monitor started. 
    2014-11-24 02:24:00.340+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 142ms [total block time: 0.142s]
    2014-11-24 02:42:44.771+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 373ms [total block time: 0.515s]
```

**neo4j.properties:**

```
dump_configuration=false
use_memory_mapped_buffers:true
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=20M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=20M   /* file cache*/
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=20M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=20M
cache_type=soft
cache.memory_radio=50%
node_cache_size=2000M
relationship_cache_size=800M 
excution_guard_enabled=true
keep_logical_logs=false
online_backup_enabled=true
ha.pull_interval=10
```

Comment: Can you share the code you used for the shortest path, and your configuration / messages.log file?

Comment: And your graph model, esp. if it contains two-bidirectional relationships of the same type between two nodes each time

Comment: yes , it contaisn wo-birdirectional relationships.Slow is ok ,if the query can timeout .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direction.BOTH is an indication that it goes in circles.

You MMIO settings should be much larger (closer to the file sizes), 
and your heap probably too (as it includes the mmio sections on Windows -> at least 12G to 16G heap).

You didn't share the part of messages.log that gives indication about heap sizes.

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=6G
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=1G
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1G
```

If you run enterprise anyway you should use:

```
cache_type=hpc
```

or

```
cache_type=none
```

For the Guard, besides setting the config you've already got, the code to add it is something like this:

```
((GraphDatabaseAPI)graphDB).getDependencyResolver().resolveDependency(Guard.class);

guard.startTimeout(timeLimit);
guard.startOperationsCount(maxOps);
try {
    return doOperation();
} catch (GuardException e) {
    LOG.warn("Aborting Operation ");
    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
} finally {
    guard.stop();
}
```

Comment: 2.che_type=hpc ,1.9.4 version does't supporty this setting

Comment: 1. "You MMIO settings should be much larger (closer to the file sizes)" It's right

Comment: 3."For the Guard, besides setting the config you've already got, the code to add it is something like this"  .It will be quite useful.   Thanks a lot  !